# This basic binary search tree algorithm causes segmentation fault:11 error

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

This simple binary search tree causes `segmentation fault:11`.

I can't understand which point of the code is making this problem.

Why this `segmentation fault:11` is occuring?

The recursive `binarySerach` function can't be wrong because it is from textbook.

So I think I have a significant ignorance in defining a tree maybe something about `malloc`.

Is it right to define `treePointer` like that??

I'm totally cursed with the error `segmentation fault:11`.

I want to know when this error occurs.

P.S. Sorry for my poor english.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct element
{
        int key;
} element;

typedef struct node *treePointer;
typedef struct node
{
        element data;
        treePointer leftChild;
        treePointer rightChild;
} node;

element* binarySearch(treePointer tree, int key);

int main(void)
{
        treePointer *a;

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
                a[i] = malloc(sizeof(node));
                a[i] -> data.key = i * 10;

                a[i] -> leftChild = NULL;
                a[i] -> rightChild = NULL;

        }
        a[0] -> leftChild = a[1];
        a[0] -> rightChild = a[2];

        a[1] -> leftChild = a[3];
        a[1] -> rightChild = a[4];

        a[2] -> leftChild = a[5];
        a[2] -> rightChild = a[6];

        a[3] -> leftChild = a[7];
        a[3] -> rightChild = a[8];

        a[4] -> leftChild = a[9];


        element* A = binarySearch(a[0], 30);
        printf("%d\n", A -> key);

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
                free(a[i]);
        }
}

element* binarySearch(treePointer tree, int key)
{
        if(!tree) return NULL;
        if(key == tree -> data.key) return &(tree -> data);
        if(key < tree -> data.key)
                return binarySearch(tree -> leftChild, key);
        return binarySearch(tree -> rightChild, key);

}
```

Comment: Sounds like an opportunity to try out a debugger.

Comment: You allocate space for the individual elements of `a`, but never for the array `a` itself. `a = malloc(10 * sizeof *a)` or similar should do that.

Comment: Where does `a` point to?

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory for `a`, too. Change its declaration to:

```
treePointer *a = malloc(10 * sizeof(treePointer));
```

And call `free(a);` at the end. Also, it's not finding the key, so it returns `NULL` which causes undefined behavior on `printf("%d\n", A->key);`. But that's because your BST isn't set up correctly. The root element has key `0` and its two children have the keys `10` and `20`, that can't be right.

Comment: I changed ```malloc```part and fixed my BST to contain right values along to the definition of BST. But this still has same ```segmentation fault:11``` error.